# Django: HAML template not rendering when testing (and no error when run normally)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-testing

I'm trying to add Selenium tests to existing project which has not used Django testing before. When run with either *runserver* or wsgi the project is working. But when I'm trying to run a test case the test fails because Django outputs HAML files sources instead of interpreting them, like if there were no TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting. I added an assertion about the setting to my test suite runner class and the assertion does not fail, so the setting is surely set.

There are no errors when I run project outside the testing environment.

N.b. I use [HamlPy](https://github.com/D3X/HamlPy) and Django 1.5 (migrating to newer version without the tests is not an option).

Where should I look for the cause of the error?

Comment: a little more info would help you better

Comment: Does the test run when you pull out all the static blocks? I'd like to see your template and settings file to help more.